# Ways in which Controller (in Spring MVC) can provide the view name to DispatcherServlet?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am working on a project, which is mainly using Spring framework.The views has been implemented using JSP and JSTLs.

Usually in various books / online tutorials which I read, the Controller class returns `ModelAndView` and based on what this object has, `DispatcherServlet` is able to return the correct view name.

Are there any other ways in which Controller (of Spring MVC) can specify the view name, for example returning a String?

Any pointer in this regards highly appreciated.

Comment: the question is weird, you need to be more specific

Comment: Hmm , thanks for your comment. However, I wanted to give some background on why I am asking this question, and my question is specific, isn't it?

Comment: No I dont get the question nor what you really want. Yes you controller can return a String, thant it will be handled by the viewsResolver which you have to configure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-viewresolver-resolver) states:

> All handler methods in the Spring Web MVC controllers must resolve to
>   a logical view name, either explicitly (e.g., **by returning a `String`**,
>   `View`, or `ModelAndView`) or implicitly (i.e., based on conventions)

So:

> Is there any other way in which the Controller (in MVC part) can
>   specify the view name, for example returning a String?

Yes, you can just specify the view name as a `String` return value. Basically you can determine the view explicitly by returning:

- A `String` representing the logical view name
- An instance of `ModelAndView`
- An instance of a `View` implementation, e.g. `RedirectView`

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, makes sense. So how does DispatcherServlet "knows" in which way the view has been provided by the controller (MVC)? We can have multiple controllers , and each can return the view in different ways, so how come the DispatcherServlet would differentiate between these scenarios? If you can explain a bit, would be of great help.

Comment: As far as I know, When `DispatcherServlet` finds the responsible controller to process the request, It will use the `HandlerAdapter`'s `handle` method which returns a `ModelAndView`.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L963

Comment: But when the controller returns the view as String, the controller isn't returning the ModelAndView, so how does DispatcherServlet differentiate these scenarios?

Comment: I'm not sure but It's the `HandlerAdapter` that wraps that `String` into a `ModelAndView`. Take a peek at `doDispatch` method https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/servlet/DispatcherServlet.java#L920

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, I would refer to the pointers provided by you.

Comment: @AliDehghani It's `ViewNameMethodReturnValueHandler`.